# Kodi(XBMC): Using Files.PrepareDownload (Invalid params. error)

Tags: json-rpc, xbmc, kodi

when i try to get fanart url with Files.PrepareDownload, it responses error.

first I get movies with VideoLibrary.GetMovies:

```
http://<ip>/jsonrpc?request={"jsonrpc": "2.0", "params": {"sort": {"order": "ascending", "method": "title"}, "properties": ["title", "art", "file"]}, "method": "VideoLibrary.GetMovies", "id": "libMovies"}
```

VideoLibrary.GetMovies Response:

```
{"id":"libMovies","jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"limits":{"end":1,"start":0,"total":1},"movies":[{"art":{"fanart":"image://http%3a%2f%2fimage.tmdb.org%2ft%2fp%2foriginal%2f3Kgu3ys6W6UZWWFty7rlTWgST63.jpg​/","poster":"image://http%3a%2f%2fimage.tmdb.org%2ft%2fp%2foriginal%2fg23cs30dCMiG4ldaoVNP1ucjs6.jpg/"},"file":"D:\\Movie\\Film\\Fantastic.Four.2015.720p.BluRay.x264-GECKOS\\Fantastic.Four.2015.720p.BluRay.x264-GECKOS.mkv","label":"Fantastic Four","movieid":1,"title":"Fantastic Four"}]}}{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"GUI.OnScreensaverActivated","params":{"data":null,"sender":"xbmc"}}
```

Then i try to get prepared url with Files.PrepareDownload:
Request:

```
http://<ip>/jsonrpc?request={"jsonrpc": "2.0", "params": {"path": "image://http%3a%2f%2fimage.tmdb.org%2ft%2fp%2foriginal%2f3Kgu3ys6W6UZWWFty7rlTWgST63.jpg​/"}, "method": "Files.PrepareDownload", "id": "preparedl"}
```

Files.PrepareDownload Response:

```
{"error":{"code":-32602,"data":{"details":null},"message":"Invalid params."},"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a POST to Files.PrepareDownload

Comment: would you give me an example about how to do it?

Comment: Have a look at this code, it might help you to understand what I mean with POST instead of GET
https://github.com/MilhouseVH/texturecache.py/blob/master/texturecache.py#L2178